# Theme or Topic - what's the difference?

Tags: synonyms

Theme or Topic - what's the difference? Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a slight difference between a *theme* and a *topic*.

*Both* can mean the *main subject* of a talk, piece of writing, film, etc:

> - The *theme* of this discussion is education.
> - The *topic* for discussion today is education.

You may have heard the expression "*stay on topic*". Anything with a "topic" usually sticks fairly rigidly to that subject. We tend to use the word with *factual* subjects rather than fictional works.

However, "theme" can also be used in a much looser way. It can mean a specific subject or a broader *idea* that recurs or runs throughout something. For example, a film or movie might deal with many different subjects yet have a *recurring theme*. Anthologies of short stories may feature many pieces by different authors, all in different settings, but all share a *common theme* that is touched on to varying degrees within each piece.